every brew command hangs without output
After terminating some brew command in the middle because it hanged for minutes, every brew command I run hangs without output, including recommended troubleshooting commands like brew config, brew doctor, brew update -d, brew irb etc'. I verified that the homebrew-core git repo is clean and up to date. I tried to create that temporary directory in its .git that some github issues mention.

For me the solution seemed to be restarting the machine, but here's some interesting debugging I did that might help you with different issues:
It turns out that brew is a bunch of shell scripts, so I can run them with bash -x and see where it hangs exactly. For me the hang happened in the git shim, and was fixed after
$ which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
$ bash -x /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
[...]
+ exec /usr/bin/env -i HOME=/Users/aursaraf SHELL=/bin/zsh PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin TERM=xterm-256color LOGNAME=aursaraf USER=aursaraf SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zWuAbnMT5N/Listeners HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE=/opt/homebrew/bin/brew HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar 'HOMEBREW_EDITOR=code-insiders -w' HOMEBREW_LIBRARY=/opt/homebrew/Library HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 HOMEBREW_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/condabin:/Users/aursaraf/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/aursaraf/.cargo/bin HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/opt/homebrew HOMEBREW_USER_CONFIG_HOME=/Users/aursaraf/.homebrew /bin/bash -p /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh update
# run that line with an added -x
$ exec /usr/bin/env -i HOME=/Users/aursaraf SHELL=/bin/zsh PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin TERM=xterm-256color LOGNAME=aursaraf USER=aursaraf SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zWuAbnMT5N/Listeners HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE=/opt/homebrew/bin/brew HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar 'HOMEBREW_EDITOR=code-insiders -w' HOMEBREW_LIBRARY=/opt/homebrew/Library HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 HOMEBREW_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/condabin:/Users/aursaraf/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/aursaraf/.cargo/bin HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/opt/homebrew HOMEBREW_USER_CONFIG_HOME=/Users/aursaraf/.homebrew /bin/bash -x -p /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh update
[..]
++ git -C /opt/homebrew rev-parse HEAD

At this point I tried to manually run this git command and it worked, so I ran the brew command again and in a separate shell ran
ps -aux | grep git

and found that actually it wasn't really git, it was /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/git, which was a bit harder to run myself (it kept complaining that only brew.sh should run it) but if I replaced /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh in the last command with /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/git I could see it run.
... and then it occurred to me that I should try restarting and the problem disappeared.

Do you happen to know, WHY restarting would be necessary here, or was this just an educated guess?
